# Modem Security on Linux

Tags: c, linux

How can I load a C program into a USB MODEM (micromax) so that whenever I connect it to any PC, it will first execute my program on the machine?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot in general enforce that your application is executed on any Linux system, but if you have admin rights on the machine, you can write `udev` rules, that automatically run a file if a specific USB drive is inserted.

You can look here to see how `udev` rules are written:

http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html

There is also a small section on "Running external programs upon certain events".